# If $G$ is finite group that supersoluble then $G$ satisfy the maximal permutizer condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The
permutizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with $H$,
i.e. $\langle x \in G | \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $, denoted by $P_G(H)$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $G$ if $P_G(H)$ strictly contains $H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $P_G(M) = G$ for any maximal subgroup $M$
of $G$.

If $G$ is finite group that supersoluble then $G$ satisfy the maximal permutizer condition ?

Comment: I tried to prove a theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It follows easily from the fact that maximal subgroups of finite supersolvable groups have prime index.

Comment: why ? which theorem ?

Comment: Let $|G:M|=p$ prime, and choose $x \in G \setminus M$ with $o(x)$ a power of $p$.